# When to use .Value with variable name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nullable

The output of `stringVar.Value` and `stringVar` in second statement are same. I just want to know when to use `stringVar.Value` and `stringVar`.

```
var stringVar= dbContext.tbl.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id)?.ColumnName;
return stringVar!= null ? stringVar.Value : 0;
```

Comment: That variable is clearly not holding a `string`, so why would you name it `stringVar`? Based on your `return` statement, it appears to be type `int?`, which is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`. You should (already have) read the documentation for the `Nullable<T>` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value?view=net-7.0) is a property of [`Nullable` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-7.0). When there is class member defined with Nullable data type, then to get actual value, you should use `.Value` property.

In your case, you used `FirstOrDefault()` with `Null propagation` operator, which will propagate null if there is no value found for specific `id`.

In next line you checked if the `stringVar` is not `null` then to get actual value you used `.Value` property otherwise return `0`

Answer (score 1):

Just refer to the declaration of `Nullable<T>`, `Value` is read-only and gives the actual value.

```
[Serializable]
[NonVersionable] // This only applies to field layout
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TypeForwardedFrom("mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")]
public partial struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    private readonly bool hasValue; // Do not rename (binary serialization)
    internal T value; // Do not rename (binary serialization) or make readonly (can be mutated in ToString, etc.)

    [NonVersionable]
    public Nullable(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        hasValue = true;
    }

    public readonly bool HasValue
    {
        [NonVersionable]
        get => hasValue;
    }

    public readonly T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!hasValue)
            {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_NoValue();
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
```